# draw a multicolumn table with row col span in overleaf

Tags: tables

i am working on overleaf  need to draw a table like given in picture.. I have this code but i got errors when i tried to modify it

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}X}
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}*{6}{Y}}
\toprule
State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value}
   &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
             &{Min}     
               &{Max} 
                  &{Low} 
                     &2hrs
                        &3hrs
                           &4hrs\\
\midrule
Healthy      
   &70            
      &100     
         &a 
            &$<$ 140
               &
                  &\\
\midrule
Pre-Diabetes 
   &101           
      &126     
         &a 
            &140 -- 200
               &
                  &\\
\midrule
Diabetes     
   &$>$126 
      &N/A     
         &a 
            &$>$ 200
               &
                  &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The code output i this
[image]

i need to add only one column at left side .. highlighred with red color
[image]

Comment: The code you posted works without error messages. Since you mention "but i got errors when i tried to modify it": what exactly did you try to modify and which error messages did you encounter? What does the expected output look like?

Comment: The code in your question contains a total of 7 columns, the last six of them are distributed in two groups of three, each. The image in your questions shows a quite different table with a total of just 6 columns and groups of 2 columns. Do you want to reproduce the table in the image?

Comment: the expected output should look like an image i posted in question. yeah that code is running without error i need to modify it as per image

Comment: What did you try so far in order to modify the code to result in an output like the one shown in the image?

Comment: thats what i am saying that i am unable to modify it i am getting errors

Comment: Well, then please show the code that results in an error message. The code you currently show in your question  is so different from the image of the expected output that I have a hard time understanding which cell's contents in the code corresponds to which cell in the image.

Comment: i updated the question i only need to make changes wit existing code is to draw another column at left side of table .. highlighted table column with red color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what is the problem but insert an extra row at the beginning of the table. You only add additional column specifier, for example `l`, to column specification and insert texts before existed columns, something like this.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l p{3cm}*{6}{Y}}
\toprule
text    & State of Health
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value}
                &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
        \cmidrule(r){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
        &   & Min 
                & Max 
                    & Low 
                        & 2hrs
                            & 3hrs
                                & 4hrs\\
        \midrule
text    & Healthy
           &70
              &100
                 &a
                    &$<$ 140
                       &
                          &\\
        \midrule
text    & Pre-Diabetes
           &101
              &126
                 &a
                    &140 -- 200
                       &
                          &\\
        \midrule
text    & Diabetes
           &$>$126
              &N/A
                 &a
                    &$>$ 200
                       &
                          &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks how to move extra text to next line in one cell?

Comment: @Alex, zwo posibilities: **(i)** by inserting some table inside cell, for example `\makecell{<first line>\\ <second line>}`, **(ii)** if  column if of "paragraph" type, for example `p{<width>}`, you can after first line insert `\newline` or empty line before second line.

Comment: getting errors let me post another question for this

Comment: @Alex, continue from my previous comment: in ""paragraph" column type, for example p{<width>},  the text in cell will be automatically broken into more lines if it is longer than width of a cell. If you get some error doing this, please ask new question.

Answer (score 3):

The first table in the following screenshot shows the result of adding a column at the start of the `tabularx` environment. (It also centers the contents of the 6 data columns.) Overall, I don't think this table looks particularly good. The second table in the screenshot shows the result of using a basic `tabular` environment. I think it's much easier to read than the `tabularx`-based table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Solution with \texttt{tabularx}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} ll *{6}{Y} @{}}
\toprule
Heading 1 & State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value} 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
 & &{Min} &{Max} &{Low}  &2hrs &3hrs &4hrs\\
\midrule
add & Healthy  &70 &100 &a  &$< 140$ & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
del & Pre-Diabetes &101  &126  &a & 140--200 & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
mult & Diabetes &$>126$ &N/A  &a & $>200$ & &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip
\centering
\caption{Solution with \texttt{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Heading 1 & State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value} 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
 & &{Min} &{Max} &{Low}  &2hrs &3hrs &4hrs\\
\midrule
add & Healthy  &70 &100 &a  &$< 140$ & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
del & Pre-Diabetes &101  &126  &a & 140--200 & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
mult & Diabetes &$>126$ &N/A  &a & $>200$ & &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if the text is too long for one cell how to move it to next line . can you help?

Comment: @Alex - Please be more specific. E.g., is it happening in one of the data columns? And, how much is "too long for one cell" -- just a millimeter, or a whole word or more?